# How to scale year interval in D3 axis without changing columns

Tags: svg, d3.js

[image]

I want to set up the year interval to every 3 years and start from 2012 in this example: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/create-bar-chart-using-d3js. How should I modify the code to make this happen? My desired output is as in the picture above.

Answer (score 1):

Hide ticks with `tickFormat`:

```
d3.axisBottom(xScale)   
  .tickFormat((d, i) => i % 3 === 0 ? 1900 + d.getYear() : null)
```

```js
const from = new Date('2010-01-01')
const to = new Date('2022-01-01')

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([from, to])
  .range([0, 400]);
  
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)   
  .tickFormat((d, i) => i % 3 === 0 ? 1900 + d.getYear() : null)

d3.select('svg').append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(50,50)`)
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100" />
```